# Holiday calendar class Error Python 3

Tags: python, pandas, compiler-errors, time-series

I have a dataset which conatins Date-Value pairs and I am using date for indexing, like that:

```
import pandas as pd

dataf = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv') 
dataf.index = pd.date_range(start='2010-01-01 00:00', periods=df.shape[0], freq='H')
```

I would like to a Holiday colmn to this dataset, which conatin True/False values depends on is is holiday or not.

---

Edited:

```
from pandas.tseries.holiday import Holiday, AbstractHolidayCalendar
import pandas as pd

dataf = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv') 
dataf.index = pd.date_range(start='2010-01-01 00:00', periods=df.shape[0], freq='H')
dataf['DATE'] = dataf.index.map(lambda x: x.date)

dater = pd.date_range(start='2010-01-01', end='2011-12-31')
newdater= pd.DataFrame()

newdater['Date']=dater

class ExampleCalendar(AbstractHolidayCalendar):
     rules = [
          Holiday('asd1',month=1, day=1),
          Holiday('asd2',month=1, day=2),
          Holiday('asd3',month=12, day=30),
          Holiday('asd4',month=12, day=31)
              ]
# So I want 4 days as Holiday in a year

cal = ExampleCalendar

holidays = cal.holidays(start='2010-01-01',end='2011-12-31')

dataf['HOLIDAY'] = dataf['DATE'].isin(holidays) 

print(dataf)
```

Output:

```
                          DATE      LOAD HOLIDAY
2010-01-01 00:00:00  2010-01-01   964.353   False
2010-01-01 01:00:00  2010-01-01   954.353   False
2010-01-01 02:00:00  2010-01-01   932.856   False
2010-01-01 03:00:00  2010-01-01   926.750   False
2010-01-01 04:00:00  2010-01-01   907.179   False
2010-01-01 05:00:00  2010-01-01   904.692   False
2010-01-01 06:00:00  2010-01-01   909.452   False
2010-01-01 07:00:00  2010-01-01   922.646   False
2010-01-01 08:00:00  2010-01-01   927.956   False
2010-01-01 09:00:00  2010-01-01   963.113   False
2010-01-01 10:00:00  2010-01-01   987.948   False
2010-01-01 11:00:00  2010-01-01  1000.232   False
2010-01-01 12:00:00  2010-01-01  1000.317   False
2010-01-01 13:00:00  2010-01-01  1006.021   False
2010-01-01 14:00:00  2010-01-01  1041.776   False
2010-01-01 15:00:00  2010-01-01  1134.506   False
2010-01-01 16:00:00  2010-01-01  1151.931   False
2010-01-01 17:00:00  2010-01-01  1147.689   False
2010-01-01 18:00:00  2010-01-01  1147.292   False
2010-01-01 19:00:00  2010-01-01  1129.979   False
2010-01-01 20:00:00  2010-01-01  1099.994   False
2010-01-01 21:00:00  2010-01-01  1059.531   False
2010-01-01 22:00:00  2010-01-01  1016.890   False
2010-01-01 23:00:00  2010-01-01   965.563   False
```

Comment: instead of `cal = AbstractHolidayCalendar` use `cal = ExampleCalendar()`

Comment: Thanks, now working, I have one more problem. Every value in Holidays column is false. Why?

Comment: could you add your code with output to the question ?